# Arrows in a presheaf category covariantly induce maps between subfunctors

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

I am currently reading Sheaves in Geometry and Logic and have hit a little bit of a snag that I can't figure out. In the book it is claimed that if $ g\colon B\longrightarrow C $ is morphism and $Q$ is a subfunctor of $Hom(\_,C)$ then this determines a subfunctor $Q'$ of $Hom(\_,B)$. The claim is that $g$ induces $Q'$ from $Q$ "by pullback". I am at a loss as to how this is induced. We want $Q'(D)$ to be a subset of $Hom(D,B)$ for any object $D$ and $Q(f:D\rightarrow D')$ to be the restriction of $Hom(f,B)$ for any arrow $f$, but I have no idea how to use $Q'$ and $g$ to create this new functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition would be
$$
Q'(D) = \{f: D \to B \mid gf \in Q(D)\}.
$$
we can easily check that $Q'(h: D \to D'): Q'(D') \to Q'(D)$ is the restriction of $\operatorname{Hom}(h, B)$ . Let $f \in Q'(D')$, then $gf \in Q(D')$, so $gfh \in Q(D)$. This follows because $Q$ is a subfunctor of $\operatorname{Hom}(-, C)$. Hence $fh \in Q'(D)$, as required.

Comment: Oh right, that makes sense. I think I was confused a little by the wording and expected to be doing either precompositions by $g$ somehow or fibred-products. That makes sense as it aligns (is exactly the same) as the definition of the pullback of a sieve with respect to some map. Thanks!

Comment: @subobject_classifier That is exactly right! By the way, as you see this has nothing to do with the subobject_classifier (pun intended?) as you mentioned in your title.

Comment: Oh this was mentioned simply because the construction used here serves the purpose of defining the object of truth values in a presheaf category but yeah it's true we don't need to have it - I'll change the title.